# Use pandas map or applymap or similar to process pairs of rows in a dataframe

Tags: pandas

I'm trying to process a counter like that that counts miles in a car into the differences between counters:

Here is the input:

```
Index,              Counter
2016-06-01 13:00:00,225907.9
2016-06-01 14:00:00,225908.9
2016-06-01 15:00:00,225909.9
2016-06-01 16:00:00,225910.9
2016-06-01 17:00:00,225911.9
2016-06-01 18:00:00,225912.9
2016-06-01 19:00:00,225913.9
```

Here is the desired output:

```
Index,              Counter,Increase
2016-06-01 13:00:00,225907.9,0.0 # by definition for the start of the df
2016-06-01 14:00:00,225908.9,1.0
2016-06-01 15:00:00,225909.9,1.0
2016-06-01 16:00:00,225910.9,1.0
2016-06-01 17:00:00,225910.9,0.0
2016-06-01 18:00:00,225911.9,1.0 
2016-06-01 19:00:00,225912.9,1.0
```

This is easy with a loop, of course: (pseudocode: this is a quick copy&paste from a problem with more columns)

```
for i in range(1,len(df)):
    (previous, current)=df.loc[row:row+1, ['Counters'].values]
    df.at[i, 'Increase'] = current[0] - previous[0]
```

But of course in python we 'prefer' not to use a loop. My question is can this calculation be done with an `applymap` or `map` or similar, where they most of the time seem to a value out of one row and return a single value: how about taking values out of two rows and returning a single value?

Comment: Your desired output does not match the input, for instance why is it not 0 for the first row and then 1.0 for all subsequent rows? Anyway you can do `df['Increase'] = df['Counter'].diff()`

Comment: Doh! As easy as that - I never thought of .diff() Thank you!

Comment: You've still not explained why your expected output is different from your description, my understanding is that it should be 0 for first row and then a series of 1.0 for all other rows

Comment: You're right, though note that the values for 16:00 and 17:00 are the same, so the increase is 0.0.

Comment: Your input data does not show that, that is my point

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's unclear how you get your output based on your input but you can do this using [`diff`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.diff.html) which is vectorised and will be much faster for large datasets:

```
In [15]:
df['Increase'] = df['Counter'].diff().fillna(0)
df

Out[15]:
                 Index   Counter  Increase
0  2016-06-01 13:00:00  225907.9       0.0
1  2016-06-01 14:00:00  225908.9       1.0
2  2016-06-01 15:00:00  225909.9       1.0
3  2016-06-01 16:00:00  225910.9       1.0
4  2016-06-01 17:00:00  225911.9       1.0
5  2016-06-01 18:00:00  225912.9       1.0
6  2016-06-01 19:00:00  225913.9       1.0
```